# FIX ImportError: cannot import name 'patterns'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am writing documentaton for the API I have already built. I have already  installed `drfdocs` and added it in `INSTALLED_APPS` then configured the urls yet I get the following logs below. I think the version of rest_framework_docs is importing `patterns` which I believe its deprecated, new versions of django are no longer using it. How do I fix this?
I have django `1.11` and  using `python3`. I get the following logs when I try to run ther server:

## Logs

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework_docs/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
ImportError: cannot import name 'patterns'
```

## Views.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
# from organizations.backends import invitation_backend
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'api/token/', obtain_auth_token, name='api-token'),
    # url(r'^account/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='account')),
    url(r'^hr/', include('hr.urls', namespace='hr')),
    url(r'^acc/', include('Accounting.urls', namespace='Accounting')),
    url(r'^payroll/', include('payroll.urls', namespace='payroll')),
    url(r'^bill/', include('bill.urls', namespace='bill')),

    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_docs.urls')),
    url(r'^proc/', include('procurement.urls', namespace='procurement')),
    # url(r'^accounts/', include('organizations.urls')),
    # url(r'^authority/', include('authority.urls')),
    url(r'^organization/', include('organizations.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # url(r'^invitations/', include(invitation_backend().get_urls())),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: What is `rest_framework_docs`? You seem to have an old version of it, which is not compatible with current Django.

Comment: If it's [this](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-framework-docs), note the big warning on that page not to use it.

Comment: yep its that one ..Thanks

Comment: I suspect you meant to install [this](https://www.drfdocs.com/) instead.

Comment: I have removed the existing one via pip uninstall then re-installed it. works like a charm :)